# How to count consecutive occurrences of a substring in a main string in Python?

Tags: python, string, recursion

I want to count the consecutive occurrences of a substring in a mainstring. After that, I want to take the number of consecutive occurrences, and have that as a return value. I wanted to do that recursively, as follows:

```
def countConsecutive (mainstr, substr, count):
    if substr in mainstr[:len(substr)]:
        count += 1
        mainstr = mainstr[len(substr):]
        countConsecutive (mainstr, substr, count)
    else:
        return count
```

I have 'count' as input, as it needs to be set to 0 every time the function is called outside the function itself. However, the problem is, the return value is a NoneType, so I can't compare it to the previous 'counts' to take the highest one. Why is it a NoneType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a None type because you actually return a None.

Notice that when you get to the else part you return the value back up the recursion stack, which goes to the previous call, back to the line `countConsecutive (mainstr, substr, count)` but you need another return statement in order to return `count` up the recursion stack all the way to the first call.

Simply change the code to:

```
def countConsecutive (mainstr, substr, count):
    if substr in mainstr[:len(substr)]:
        count += 1
        mainstr = mainstr[len(substr):]
        return countConsecutive (mainstr, substr, count) #added return statement
    else:
        return count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     def countConsecutive(mainstr, substr, count):
        if substr in mainstr[:len(substr)]:
            count += 1
            mainstr = mainstr[len(substr):]
            return countConsecutive (mainstr, substr, count) #added return statement
        else:
            return count
```

This solution will only return the count if the repeat substring is at the start of the mainstr. This example below returns 0 when there are 3 repeats:

```
    >>> mainstr = "blue redredred blue red blue green red"
    >>> substr = "red"
    >>> count = 0
    >>> print(countConsecutive(mainstr, substr, count))
    0
```

The follow returns the highest number of substr repeats in the main string:

```
    def countConsecutive(mainstr, substr, count, best=0):
        if len(mainstr) > 0:               
        # terminal case
            if substr in mainstr[:len(substr)]:
                # hit: move along len(substr), add to count, update best
                count += 1
                mainstr = mainstr[len(substr):]
                if count > best:
                    best = count
            else:
                # miss: move along 1, reset counter
                mainstr = mainstr[1:]
                count = 0

            return countConsecutive(mainstr, substr, count, best=best)

        else:
            return best
```

The same test case now returns 3:

```
    >>> mainstr = "blue redredred blue red blue green red"
    >>> substr = "red"
    >>> count = 0
    >>> print(countConsecutive(mainstr, substr, count))
    3
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple solution of using default as follows:

```
def countConsecutive (mainstr, substr, count=0):
```

Comment: Have you tested this simple solution? I am pretty convinced it doesn't solve the problem.